# Wrapping C++ coroutines to use in Python with Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am working on a project where I want to run code for some tests async in Python. I have C++ functions that are coroutines (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines), and I need to be able to wrap these coroutine functions in Cython. These functions take in tasks (https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/tasks). Is there a way to wrap coroutine functions in Cython to be used in Python tests?

Thanks!